# How can I remove Buttons in Pixi?

Tags: javascript, game-development, pixi.js

When I remove a scene, the previous buttons will still be clickable. Not visible, but clickable.

I try to code a Game with Pixi an have different scenes like the menu, etc. I use the GitHub Tutorial from KittyKatattack. I just removed the scene, where the buttons were attatched to, but that doesnt work. Also removing the button itself doesnt help.

`

```
let playButtonFrames = [id["playButtonUp.png"], id['playButtonDown.png']];
playButton = t.button(playButtonFrames);
playButton.y = window.innerHeight/2 - playButton.height/2 - 150;
playButton.x = window.innerWidth/2 - playButton.width/2;
t.makeInteractive(playButton);
playButton.press = () => {
    console.log('U');
    state = chooseMap;
}
```

That is the setup for the button. chooseMap() looks like this:

```
function chooseMap() {
    app.stage.removeChild(menuScene);
    app.stage.addChild(chooseMapScene);

}
```

The Img of the Button dissapears, but its still clickable.

There are no Error Messages. And well... I want the button to be fully removed when I change the scene.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

By looking into the very well organized and by comments documented Source Code of PIXI's tink.js, I found out that

```
button.enabled = false;
```

does the trick. Props go to myself.

EDIT: Well, apparently, the mechanics can be turned off that way, but the button is still there. The 'cursor: pointer' shows up when you hover over that position where the but was.